# How can I overwrite an array of chars (AKA a string), with a new array of chars in C?

Tags: c, arrays, char, incompatibletypeerror

```
int main(void) {
  ...
  char A[32] = "00000000000000001111111111111110"; 
  ...
  A = "11111111111111111111111111111111";
}
```

This is erroneous c-code for what I want to do.  I want the string in memory to be overwritten with a new string of the same length.  I keep getting incompatible types -like errors.

Comment: Your declaration of `A` is probably off by one.

Comment: @mu is too short: The code in the question is legal C, it's an array of 32 `char`, initialised with the given 32 characters. There's no requirement to have a NUL terminator in `A`, unless you want to treat it as a NUL-terminated string. The compiler knows that the NUL terminator won't fit, and doesn't copy it when performing the initialisation of `A` from the constant string.

Comment: @Greg: Hence the *probably* qualification. It looks like a string and smells like a string we don't know if it is a string or just an array of characters. The initialization makes it look like a string so I'd flag it as, at least, ambiguous in a code review. We don't know how `A` is used so we don't know if it is an error, we only know that it looks suspicious. The presence of `strcpy` and `strncpy` in the answers indicates that it is ambiguous, `memcpy` indicates that some people noticed the ambiguity and are trying to account for it.

Comment: You're absolutely right, using *probably* was the correct choice of words. :)

Comment: Technically, `strncpy` isn't intended for dealing with null terminated strings, but null _padded_ strings. It's just that the latter are rather uncommon these days even within fixed-size struct members.

Answer (score 5):

Use [strncpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy):

```
char chararray[6];
(void)strncpy(chararray, "abcdefgh", sizeof(chararray));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `strcpy(char *destination, const char *source);`.

```
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  ...
  char A[32] = "00000000000000001111111111111110"; 
  ...
  strcpy(A, "11111111111111111111111111111111");
}
```

Though safer is `strncpy(char *destination, const char *source, size_t num)`, which will only copy `num` amount of characters, preventing going out of bounds on the destination:

```
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  ...
  char A[32] = "00000000000000001111111111111110"; 
  ...
  strncpy(A, "11111111111111111111111111111111", sizeof(A));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
memcpy(A,"11111111111111111111111111111111",32);
```

Answer (score 1):

Among other possible ways, you can do

```
memcpy(A, "11111 etc.", 32);
```

You want to make 32 into a named constant, at the least. You also have to be careful of buffer overflows; in C this is not checked.

Answer (score 0):

have a look into the library function `strcpy`.